# A generic function that will return the results of a SELECT query from a local MySQL database - C# .Net 4.6.1

Tags: c#, mysql, select

I'm using a MySQL local database, connecting to the database is not a problem (anymore). I have a small-scale database with around 6 different tables, each with around 4-6 columns, and rows <100 (not working with large data).

I am creating a WPF application that only ever needs to SELECT data from these databases, it never needs to add to them. The database is filled with static data which I will need to run SELECT statements on it and then use the results to display in my WPF app.

I need to make a function in my DBHandler class which can then be called from any other class in my system, to query the database with a specified SELECT statement, and then use the results. The problem is that my queries will vary - sometimes I might be calling for one column, such as;

```
(SELECT id FROM students WHERE name = 'Conor')
```

Sometimes I might be calling for multiple rows in a more complex statement.. such as this (pseudo):

```
(SELECT name, address FROM destinations WHERE long, lat intersects_with (SELECT long, lat FROM trains))
```

Whenever I call this function with a query, I will always be expecting the format of the data response, so if I just return a List<> or array, it should be no problem accessing the data even though the function is generic and not specific for one query or table.

So far I have tried this:

```
    public static MySqlDataReader Query(string SQLQuery)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(SQLQuery, con);

            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            return reader;
        }
    }

    // Some other class
    MySqlDataReader reader = DBHandler.Query("SELECT * FROM destinations");

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(reader[0].ToString());
    }
```

This doesn't work, because it complains the reader is closed. I presume I can't simply return a MySqlDataReader object.

My next thought process would be to do the actual query and return all the data in this Query function, and store all the results which can then be returned. But **how** I return the data is my main issue, because it needs to be generic for variable SELECT queries, so it can't have a fixed size for number of rows or columns returned. I thought maybe I could store it in a List<>, or a List<> within a List<>, but I'm really not sure on how to lay it out.

I know this is asking a lot but it is boggling my mind - I don't know how to make this generic SELECT function, but I know it will be really helpful as I will just need to call this whenever I need to get data in another part of the system.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot try to use a DataReader when its connection has been closed. So, when your code exits the using block, the connection is closed as well the reader.  However, you can pass to your Query method an [Action delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) that receives a MySqlDataReader. This function will be defined by the caller of Query so you can customize it for your different tables while keeping a generic approach to the boilerplate code used to open, query and read the database.

```
public static MySqlDataReader Query(string SQLQuery, Action<MySqlDataReader> loader)
{
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        using(MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(SQLQuery, con))
        using(MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
           // here you can pass the reader, you are still inside the using block
           while(reader.Read())
              loader.Invoke(reader)
        }
    }
}
```

In the caller code you could write

```
List<Destination> destinations = new List<Destination>();
MySqlDataReader reader = DBHandler.Query("SELECT * FROM destinations", dataLoaderForDestination);
Console.WriteLine("Loaded " + destinations.Count + " destinations");

private void dataLoaderForDestination(MySqlDataReader reader)
{
    Destination dest = new Destination();
    dest.Address = reader.GetString(0);
    dest.Nation = reader.GetInt32(1);
    ...
    destinations.Add(dest);
}
```

Of course in a different point of your code you could pass the reference to a different Action delegate tailored for a different set of data returned by your query

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
private void dataLoaderForStudents(MySqlDataReader reader)
{
    Student st = new Student();
    st.Name = reader.GetString(0);
    st.Class = reader.GetInt32(1);
    students.Add(st);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I think this will be really helpful, I'll give it a shot in the next half an hour. One thing I want to mention though, is that I don't have classes in my project that correspond to the tables in the database. For example, I don't have Student or Destination classes that hold these properties. I would simply access the data and use the results directly, once. I assume I can still use your method, but I would just create a function every time I use a SQL query and analyse the data there.

Comment: I suggest you to create classes for each table. Your life will be a lot easier. (In any case if you want to use a `List<T>` approach, you need to be clear what that T is)

Comment: Okay I will do that. In fact, I might just store all information in lists such as List<Destination>, List<Student> rather than a database overall, because it is a small amount of data and static - I never need to add or remove. I can just loop through the lists to look for relationships. Maybe this is actually a better idea? Sorry, that kind of obseletes your generous knowledge and advice - maybe somebody else will one day use it :)

Answer (score 0):

a reader is online, you need to loop inside (using connection), because if you leave the using, the connction is disposed and closed

Comment: I gathered the reader isn't the way to go, I appreciate your response although it doesn't provide me with much help in the bigger picture. 

How would I go about using a 'loop inside (using connection)'? Also, how would I return these values from the function, so as it can be used generically returning variable formats of responses?